# GraphQL validation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am trying out relay-treasure hunt tutorial but getting the following error when I run **npm start**. I did update my schema by running **npm run update-schema**.

```
Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation error ``Cannot query field "game" on type "Query".`` in file `/home/tharaka/My Projects/relay-treasurehunt/js/routes/AppHomeRoute.js`. Try updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently added.
```

Here's what's inside my AppHomeRoute.js

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class extends Relay.Route {
    static path = '/';  
    static queries = {
        game: () => Relay.QL`query { game }`,
    };
    static routeName = 'AppHomeRoute';
}
```

Comment: What does your server side code look like? The `Query` GraphQLObjectType needs to have a property called `fields` with a func that returns an object with a `game` property.

Comment: Here's the [complete code](https://github.com/tharakabimal/relay-treasurehunt)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to query everything through either `node` or `viewer`, because those are the only fields on the root query type. So maybe try this:

```
query {
  viewer {
    game
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `data/schema.js` file...

```js
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    node: nodeField,
    // Add your own root fields here
    viewer: {
      type: gameType,
      resolve: () => getGame(),
    },
  }),
});
```

Change the `viewer` property to `game`. Like this...

```js
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    node: nodeField,
    // Add your own root fields here
    game: {
      type: gameType,
      resolve: () => getGame(),
    },
  }),
});
```

The name of that property needs to match the field you're querying on in your fragment on your Home route. I suppose as an alternative you could change your route to request `viewer` instead of `game`. Do whichever feels better.